# save list in binary file in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, save, binaryfiles

I have a code that saves data in the data file are saved without any problem.But I also tried to save an array but the array was not saved and I get an error.I keep the data (and also the array) in BinaryFormatter.The error indicates the line bf.Serialize (file, data) before closing the file in the save function.

the code

```
 public class SaveLoadScript : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public int allMoneyOfplayer, allXpOfPlayer, laval, maxXp, howMuchUpMaxXp;
     public float highTime;
     public List<GunScript> gun = new List<GunScript>();
     public void Start()
     {
         Save();
     }
     public void Update()
     {
 
     }
     public void Save()
     {
         BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
         FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/saveG.file");
         PlayerData data = new PlayerData();
         data.money = allMoneyOfplayer;
         data.xp = allXpOfPlayer;
         if (highTime > data.time)
             data.time = highTime;
         data.laval = laval;
         data.maxXp = maxXp;
         data.howMuchUpMaxXp = howMuchUpMaxXp;
         for (int i = 0; i < gun.Count; i++)
             data.gun.Add(gun[i]);
         bf.Serialize(file, data);
         file.Close();
     }
     public void Load()
     {
         if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/saveG.file"))
         {
             BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
             FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/saveG.file", FileMode.Open);
             PlayerData data = (PlayerData)bf.Deserialize(file);
             allMoneyOfplayer = data.money;
             allXpOfPlayer = data.xp;
             highTime = data.time;
             laval = data.laval;
             maxXp = data.maxXp;
             howMuchUpMaxXp = data.howMuchUpMaxXp;
             file.Close();
         }
     }
 }
 [System.Serializable]
 class PlayerData
 {
     public int money;
     public int xp;
     public float time;
     public int laval;
     public int maxXp;
     public int howMuchUpMaxXp;
     public List<GunScript> gun = new List<GunScript>();
 }
```

the error

```
SerializationException: Type 'GunScript' in Assembly 'Assembly-CSharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.
```

System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMembers (System.RuntimeType type) (at :0)
System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices+<>c__DisplayClass9_0.b__0 (System.Runtime.Serialization.MemberHolder _) (at :0)
System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2[TKey,TValue].GetOrAdd (TKey key, System.Func`2[T,TResult] valueFactory) (at :0)
System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers (System.Type type, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context) (at :0)
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitMemberInfo () (at :0)
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize (System.Type objectType, System.Runtime.Serialization.ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context, System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, System.Runtime.Serialization.IFormatterConverter converter, System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationBinder binder) (at :0)
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.Serialize (System.Type objectType, System.Runtime.Serialization.ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context, System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, System.Runtime.Serialization.IFormatterConverter converter, System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationBinder binder) (at :0)
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.WriteArray (System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.NameInfo memberNameInfo, System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo memberObjectInfo) (at :0)
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Write (System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.NameInfo memberNameInfo, System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.NameInfo typeNameInfo) (at :0)
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize (System.Object graph, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.Header[] inHeaders, System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryWriter serWriter, System.Boolean fCheck) (at :0)
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize (System.IO.Stream serializationStream, System.Object graph, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.Header[] headers, System.Boolean fCheck) (at :0)

Comment: post GunScript.cs code

Comment: Is it add [System.Serializable] attribute?

Comment: i add GunScript.cs code

Comment: you need add Serializable attribute in save class

Comment: [**STOP using `BinaryFormatter`!**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide)

Answer (score 0):

```
[System.Serializable] //<-- add this attribute
public class GunScript
```

Comment: I added to the GunScript class [System.Serializable] and I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

I don't get any errors but my script doesn't load or possibly save my array...

here's the first script

```
[System.Serializable]
public class PlayerData
{
    public float health;
    public float thirst;
    public float hunger;
    public float oxygen;
    public float[] position;
    public int[] inventoryIDs;

    public PlayerData (Health healthO, SaveLoad saveload)
    {
        //Save int items
        health = healthO.health;
        thirst = healthO.thirst;
        hunger = healthO.hunger;
        oxygen = healthO.oxygen;

        //set and save location array
        position = new float[3];

        position[0] = healthO.transform.position.x;
        position[1] = healthO.transform.position.y;
        position[2] = healthO.transform.position.z;

        //set and save inventory IDs
        inventoryIDs = new int[50];

        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            inventoryIDs[i] = saveload.IDs[i];
        }
    }
}
```

here's the next

```
public class SaveLoad : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;

    public int[] IDs;

    public GameObject[] objects;

    Inventory inventory;
    Health health;

    void Start()
    {
        IDs = new int[50];
        objects = new GameObject[50];

        inventory = player.GetComponent<Inventory>();
        health = player.GetComponent<Health>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //Add IDs
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            IDs[i] = inventory.slot[i].GetComponent<Slot>().ID;
        }

        //debug save load test
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z))
        {
            SaveP();
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X))
        {
            LoadP();
        }

    }

    public void SaveP()
    {
        SaveSystem.SavePlayer(health, this);
    }

    public void LoadP()
    {
        PlayerData data = SaveSystem.LoadPlayer();

        //load stats
        health.thirst = data.thirst;
        health.hunger = data.hunger;
        health.health = data.health;
        health.oxygen = data.oxygen;

        //Load position
        Vector3 position;
        position.x = data.position[0];
        position.y = data.position[1];
        position.z = data.position[2];
        player.transform.position = position;

        //load IDs
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            IDs[i] = data.inventoryIDs[i];
        }

        //Load Items
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            if(objects[IDs[i]] != null)
            {
                GameObject itemObject = (GameObject)Instantiate(objects[IDs[i]], new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);

                Item item = itemObject.GetComponent<Item>();

                inventory.AddItem(itemObject, item.ID, item.type, item.name, item.description, item.icon);
            } else
            {
                return;
            }
           
        }

    }

}
```

Here's the last script

```
public static class SaveSystem
{
    public static string fileName = "FileSave.bin";

    public static void SavePlayer(Health health, SaveLoad SL)
    {
        //Create formatter
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

        // Create file stream
        FileStream file = File.Create(GetFullPath());

        //Save data
        PlayerData data = new PlayerData(health, SL);
        bf.Serialize(file, data);

        //Close stream
        file.Close();
    }

    public static PlayerData LoadPlayer()
    {
        if (SaveExists())
        {
            try
            {
                //Create formatter
                BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

                //Create file stream
                FileStream file = File.Open(GetFullPath(), FileMode.Open);

                //Load data
                PlayerData pd = (PlayerData)bf.Deserialize(file);

                //close stream
                file.Close();

                //return data
                return pd;
            }

            catch (SerializationException)
            {
                Debug.Log("Failed to load file at: " + GetFullPath());
            }
        }

        return null;

    }

    private static bool SaveExists()
    {
        return File.Exists(GetFullPath());
    }

    private static string GetFullPath()
    {
        return Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + fileName;
    }

}
```

there are all connected with the save load script loading and saving the variables into the player and items to the inventory sots. the inventory IDs array isn't saving or loading

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31926850)